# Is it possible to make one item in QTreeView clickable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm using QTreeView as view and QAbstractItemModel as model.
This is how my app looking right now:[image]

I want to make this field(**url**) on the right view clickable, not editable, so user can click on it and open url.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ModMetaData>
  <name>Hospitality</name>
  <author>Orion</author>
  <url>https://ludeon.com/forums/index.php?topic=11444.0</url>
  <targetVersion>0.14.1241</targetVersion>
</ModMetaData>
```

Kind regards, Maxim.

Comment: The QTreeView is on the left side, the field url is on the right side in the QTableView. You want to make it possible to click on a field in a QTableView, don't you?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. They both are QTreeView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing we do is disable the editing of the items with

```
{your treeview}.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
```

Then we connect the clicked event to a slot (in my case on_clicked), from the QModelIndex we get the Item, and consequently the text associated with the latter, we then launch the opening Url with:

```
QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl({your url}))
```

**Complete code:**

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QIODevice, QUrl
from PyQt5.QtGui import QDesktopServices, QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QApplication, QTreeView
from PyQt5.QtXml import QDomDocument


class CustomTreeView(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTreeView, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.mdl = QStandardItemModel()
        self.mdl.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["tag", "value"])
        self.setModel(self.mdl)
        self.readXML('item.xml')
        self.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        self.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)

    def on_clicked(self, index):
        text = self.mdl.itemFromIndex(index).text()
        QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl(text))

    def readXML(self, filename):
        doc = QDomDocument("doc")
        file = QFile(filename)
        if not file.open(QIODevice.ReadOnly):
            return
        if not doc.setContent(file):
            file.close()
            return
        file.close()

        rootNode = self.mdl.invisibleRootItem()

        docElem = doc.documentElement()
        node = docElem.firstChild()
        while not node.isNull():
            element = node.toElement()
            if not element.isNull():
                tag = QStandardItem(element.tagName())
                value = QStandardItem(element.text())
                # tag.setEditable(False)
                # value.setEditable(False)
                rootNode.appendRow([tag, value])
            node = node.nextSibling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = CustomTreeView()
    w.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image]